# Why is Odata changing datetime value in filter based off my machines local time if Z suffix is specified?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using Odata V4 on my asp.net web api. When i make this request using odata to filter by datetime, it subtracts 8 hours (my computer local time is set to pacific standard time UTC -8:00) from the date i provide in the url from the date that entity framework sends to my DB.

```
...Documents?$select=Id,ModifiedDate&$filter=ModifiedDate ge 2018-02-10T00:00:00Z&$orderby=ModifiedDate
```

Here is the log of this request Entity Framework provides.

```
Opened connection at 2/9/2018 5:16:40 PM -08:00
SELECT TOP (101) 
    [Project1].[DocumentId] AS [DocumentId], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[C3] AS [C2], 
    [Project1].[C4] AS [C3], 
    [Project1].[C5] AS [C4], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C5]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[DocumentId] AS [DocumentId], 
        [Extent1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate], 
         CAST( [Extent1].[DocumentId] AS bigint) AS [C1], 
        N'8da97389-55d6-4534-b683-2e767485606a' AS [C2], 
        N'ModifiedDate' AS [C3], 
         CAST( [Extent1].[ModifiedDate] AS datetime2) AS [C4], 
        N'Id' AS [C5]
        FROM [dbo].[EstimateDocument] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ModifiedDate] >= convert(datetime2, '2018-02-09 16:00:00.0000000', 121)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[ModifiedDate] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
-- Executing at 2/9/2018 5:16:40 PM -08:00
-- Completed in 435 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

It seems that odata is subtracting 8 hours from the time i said to filter by. I thought the Z at the end of the date i specified in the url stands for UTC time. Why is Odata changing this date before making the request? The dates stored in the db are also in UTC time. Why would it think any conversion needs to happen?

I have noticed if i change my computers local time to UTC (my service runs locally) then it does not try and make any conversions. But i cannot expect the service to run on a machine who's local time is set to UTC.

Comment: Where you able to fix this (outside of setting timezone for the app)?

Answer (score 3):

On your Api, where you define UseMvc, add SetTimeZoneInfo(TimeZoneInfo.Utc).

Comment: Solved for me .

Comment: FYI, a recent .NET Core version of OData (8.0) had a similar bug (same?) that was just fixed and added to the 8.0.2 release.
Issue: https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/issues/268
Release: https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/releases/tag/8.0.2